# Size O(1/N) error term of sum of logs

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to derive an asymptotic expression for $N\to \infty$ for the classic sum:

$$ \sum_{n\leq N} \log n = \log (N!)$$

But with the error of the size $O(1/N)$.

I am using the standard methodology of applying *Euler's summation* but (obviously) I can only get the usual result:

$$\sum_{n\leq N} \log n = N\log N-N+2 +\int_1^N\{t\}t^{-1} dt - \{N\}\log N  $$

which gives

$$ \sum_{n\leq N} \log n = N\log N-N+ O(\log N) $$

*Is there really any way to derive an asymptotic formula with error $O(1/N)$?*

Thanks in advance for any hints on how can I proceed!

Comment: Do you know about [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation)?

Comment: Wikipedia gives an estimate for $n!$ which, when you take the logarithm, gives an error of $o(1/n),$ even better, but only a suggestion of a proof. It gives: $$n\log n-n+\frac12\log(2\pi n)+\frac1{12n}+ o\left(1/n\right)$$ 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation?wprov=sfti1

Comment: I think you can use the even more detailed Stirling series on that page to replace the $o(1/n)$ with $\frac1{96n^2}+o(1/n^2).$ More terms gets more and more complicated, but there is enough there to get to $o(1/n^5).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\frac{1}{96n^2}$? The series is $\frac{1}{12n}-\frac{1}{360n^3}+\frac{1}{1260n^5}-\ldots$.

Comment: Tried to calculate the first terms of $$\log\left(1+\frac1{12n}+\frac1{288n^2}+o(1/n^2)\right)$$ in my head, and failed. Interesting the result appears odd. @Gary

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is because the the odd-order Bernoulli numbers are all $0$ except $B_1$. See [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E1) for the general result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Low-order_cases) in the form
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f(k)}  = \int_1^n {f(x){\rm d}x}  + \frac{{f(n) + f(1)}}{2} + \int_1^n {f'(x)\left( {\left\{ x \right\} - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right){\rm d}x} .
$$
Taking $f(x)=\log x$ yields
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log k}  = \left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{1}{x}\left( {\left\{ x \right\} - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right){\rm d}x} .
$$
Integration by parts gives
\begin{align*}
\int_1^n {\frac{1}{x}\left( {\left\{ x \right\} - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right){\rm d}x} = & - \int_1^n {\frac{1}{{2x^2 }}(\left\{ x \right\}  - \left\{ x \right\}^2{\rm )d}x} 
\\ =& - \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{2x^2 }}(\left\{ x \right\} - \left\{ x \right\}^2{\rm )d}x}  +  \int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{2x^2 }}(\left\{ x \right\}  - \left\{ x \right\}^2{\rm )d}x} .
\end{align*}
The first integral converges to a constant, the second integral is clearly $\mathcal{O}\!\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ (you can show in fact that its value is between $0$ and $ \frac{1}{8n}$). Thus
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log k}  = \left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + C + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. One can then show, using for example the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), that $C=\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$.